# I want to add my two database file into commit, but there was a trouble occurs

Tags: c#, sql, git, github, command

I works on git-bash window, and when I want to add my database file in commit there was problem occurs
when I try to do this command "$ git add --all"
the problem says:
"error: open("folders/db_cafe.mdf"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file 'folders/db_cafe.mdf'
fatal: adding files failed"

can anyone help me to upload these two files on github ?

I tryed to stop the sqlexpress from the services, but nothing happened
I know that the cause is the premision of these files but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Instead of putting the MDF under git, it is better to use Sql Server Management Studio to export a script that recreates the database schema, eventually with some static data required for your application startup. Then save this file in your repository

Comment: Why don't you push a backup (instead of the mdf file, managed by sqlserver)?

Comment: can you show the script that solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

You would want to exclude the .mdf and .ldf files from git. They are not source code, they are runtime data. If you still for some reason really need to push this file to git, it needs to be unlocked. The locking will be due to an active instance of SQL Server which has it opened. Stop that instance, and the lock will be released.

Comment: can help me how to do this ?